# Modifying All Values in Data Frame Column With tolower()

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data frame and the first column (called company) is filled with various company names, but the case isn't uniform. One might be phillips while another is Phillips, and a third phiLlips. I want to make them standardized - all lower case, so I tried mutate(), with replace() and tolower():

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
refine_original <- read_csv("~/Desktop/refine_original.csv")


# cleaning up the company names to match (case)
refine_original %>% mutate(company=replace(company, length(company), 
tolower(company)))

print(refine_original$company)
```

When I print the column contents though, it looks like I didn't make the changes stick to the data frame, they remain unchanged. Any input or help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `refine_original$company <- tolower(refine_original$company)`

Comment: `refine_original %>% mutate(company=tolower(company))` if you want to stay in the dplyr world. Your original code replaces only the last value of `company` with a lower case version because you specified `length(company)` as the index to `replace`.

Comment: Got it, I knew I was missing something simple, thank you!